# Using lapply() to generate igraph properties in R

Tags: r, igraph, lapply

I have a set of networks representing lexical knowledge of 5 speakers. Each speaker was recorded a number of times, and there are 93 networks overall, all differing in size. I have used `lapply()` to generate data on average path length and mean degree (k), for each of the 93 networks. A summary of this data is shown below

```
 head(df1)

   # A tibble: 6 x 7
   Speaker   session path_length mean_k vocab_size subj_session
   <chr>   <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl>       <int> <chr>       
 1 Alex       16            1.07    6.5          7 Alex_16     
 2 Alex       17            1.04    8.6          9 Alex_17     
 3 Alex       18            1.1     3.6          4 Alex_18     
 4 Alex       19            1.19   27.5         34 Alex_19     
 5 Alex       20            1.25   35.8         47 Alex_20     
 6 Alex       21            1.15   35.9         42 Alex_21
```

I am now trying to generate a random small-world network plot based on these real data using the Watts-Strogatz method. The code I use to do this in `igraph` is, for row 1 of the tibble above, `sample_smallworld(1, 7, 6.5, 0.05, loops = FALSE, multiple = FALSE)`, where 7 is the number of nodes in the network, and 6.5 is the average degree. Once I have this data, I use `mean_distance()` to calculate the average path length for the data.

I have tried to run this across the 93 items in my data using `lapply()`:

```
 library(igraph)

 sample <- lapply(df1, FUN = function(element) {
   element <- as.data.frame(element)
   size <- element$vocab_size
   nei <- element$mean_k
   smallworldnetwork <- sample_smallworld(1, size, nei, 0.05, loops = FALSE, multiple = FALSE)
   output <- mean_distance(smallworldnetwork, directed = F)
   })
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Error in sample_smallworld(1, size + 1, nei, 0.05, loops = FALSE, multiple = FALSE) :
> At games.c:2963 : WS game: lattice size should be at least one, Invalid value

I am quite new to `lappy()` so there may simply be an error with the code, but from playing around with this I get the impression that `sample_smallworld()` won't take a non-numeric value for neighbourhood size, and I can't figure out a way to get around this.

Comment: The issue is that `lapply` loops over the columns of your df instead of the rows. To loop over the rows try `sample <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), FUN = function(row) { element <- as.data.frame(df1[row, ]) ....`

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! I was hoping it would be a simple solution!